# Detecting TCP connections by parsing traffic

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, connection

I have a C++ program running on Windows 7 that catches *all* network layer traffic and injecting it back to the Windows network stack. 
Now, I need to keep track of every ongoing tcp session/connection and assign every tcp packet (inbound and outbound) to one of those connections. 
Detecting the beginning of a new connection is not that hard. I just need to scan every tcp packet and check if its SYN flag is set. 
However I am not quite sure how to handle the end of a connection and I have three questions:

1.) The usual way to end a tcp connection is with a 4-way-handshake using the FIN flag. After the side that first sent the FIN packet receives the final ACK of the other side, it needs to wait a certain amount of time until the connection gets finally terminated. How long should this timeout be? Is this timeout time Windows specific?

2.) How should I detect half-open connections that occur when e.g. one side crashes and is therefore unable to send a FIN packet?

3.) Is there maybe a possibility to ask Windows if a certain connection is still active or not?

Comment: "*Is there maybe a possibility to ask Windows if a certain connection is still active or not*" I doubt this.

Comment: 1) [TIME_WAIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance) is configurable, [SO_KEEPALIVE](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) is dynamically configurable.  2) Here is a good discussion on detecting half-open conditions: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html (also relates to 3))

Comment: Is this just tagged C and C++ because of the Windows-APIs? I feel this question is not related to C neither to C++.

Comment: @alk - the OP clearly says this is related to a "C++ program"

Comment: @paulsm4: You are right, please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @paulsm4: So why then please the C tag is useful?

Comment: There is an interesting tag fight. I go with @alk, Windows and not C. I wonder why the Windows tag was deleted by the commenter paulsm4 who linked to a Microsoft page.

Comment: Just use long enough timeout you do not need to detect end of connection reliably

Comment: "How long should this timeout be? Is this timeout time Windows specific?" why do you care?